# ASP.NET telerik radUpload doesn't work in IE

Tags: asp.net, file-upload, telerik

I'm using telerik radUpload control to build a page like gmail file upload, I open a display:none radUpload control using following code:

```
    <telerik:RadUpload ID="RadUpload1" Runat="server"   OnClientAdded="onClientAdded" ControlObjectsVisibility="None" Localization-Select="abcd"></telerik:RadUpload>
<script type="text/javascript">
var $fileInput;
function onClientAdded(sender, args) {
$fileInput = $telerik.$(args._fileInputField);
}
function OpenDialog() {
$fileInput.click();
uploadTimer();
}
</script>
```

his is my UploadTimer function:

```
function uploadTimer() {
try {
var t = setTimeout("uploadTimer()", 500);
//var v = $("#RadUpload1").val();
var upload = $find("<%= RadUpload1.ClientID %>");
value = upload.getFileInputs()[0].value;
//IE?
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE") != -1) {
//if (value != '') {
$("#btnSubmit").click();//}
}
else//non IE?
{if (value != '') {
$("#btnSubmit").click();}
}}
catch (err) {}}
```

I click on this button to display my radUpload, then a timer is called which calls a button server side click function save radUpload selected file to the server, but I have no file uploaded in IE, what is going wrong?

```
<input type="button" value="select file" style="font-family:Tahoma;" onclick="OpenDialog()" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you wrapping any of the code in an AJAX panel or UpdatePanel?  You can't use AJAX with that control to perform the update.

Instead, if you want AJAX uploading of files, similar to how Gmail does it, use the RadAsyncUpload: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/asyncupload-overview.html